# Is It possible to make a Transparent Mask like making an window, on AS3 Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, mask, movieclip

I want to have a movieclip make a hole on another movieclip, like putting a window on a wall. I can make a mask that has the same effect as right-clicking a layer and masking it, but that is not what I want. I want to make a transparent hole.

I have tried something like this:

```
mc1 = new green(); 
mc2 = new blue(); 

mc2.blendMode = BlendMode.ALPHA; 

addChild(mc1); 
addChild(mc2); 
mc2.cacheAsBitmap = true; 
mc1.mask = mc2;
```

And this:

```
mc1.cacheAsBitmap = true;

mc2.cacheAsBitmap = true;

mc1.setMask(mc2);
```

First problem: The code gives me errors.
Second problem: Doesn't make a hole on the movieclip, just does a normal mask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your code, revised:

```
var mc1 = new green(); //included var before variable name
var mc2 = new blue();

mc2.blendMode = BlendMode.ERASE; //this masking shape will ERASE what's below it
MovieClip(root).blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER; //setting root to LAYER so this works

addChild(mc1); 
addChild(mc2); 
mc2.cacheAsBitmap = true;
```

It appears you are trying to create an 'inverted mask,' where the mask reveals everything under it *except* for where it is located. This effect can be achieved by giving your `mc2` a blend mode of `BlendMode.ERASE` instead of `BlendMode.ALPHA`.

Check out [this article](http://franto.com/inverse-masking-disclosed/) for reference.